# Connection fails, database has '.' in name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord

I've been trying to debug a SQL Server database error in one of our rails apps. The problem is that the database name, as added in database.yaml, has a `'.'` in it (`'testdb.v1'`). It results in the error:

```
TinyTds::Error: Database 'testdb' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

Thinking that this was a YAML vs. Rails issue with quoting of the '.' character, I opened the app in rails console and tried every kind of Ruby quoting I could think of, but I get the same error each time.

Somewhere down the line from the assignment of the database name in my `model.connection_config`, the '.' is being interpreted as a format specifier and the suffix is dropped from the name. `model.connection_config['database']` has `'testdb.v1'`, as it should, but clearly that's not what's being handed to SQL Server.

I wasn't sure if this is a rails issue or a SQL Server issue, though a C# app I tossed together manages to open the database without problems. Thus, I assume it's a rails/ActiveRecord issue. Unfortunately, I don't have the option of changing the database name.

Is there a way to quote the '.' character so that it will maintain the '.' and the suffix in the database name?

Comment: hmm, did you try variations with backslash \?

Comment: I have tried a few variations. Using 'testdb\.v1' gives the same error, except the interpreted database name comes out 'testdb\.v1'. That is, Rails passes the backslash to SQL Server, where it assumes it's part of the name.

Comment: Can you try wrapping the database name with square brackets eg '[testdb.v1]'?

Comment: When I try that I get "TinyTds::Error: Database '[testdb]' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.: USE [[testdb].[v1]]]" When I try the suggested bracketing, I'm back to the original error. Seems like there might be something going on in the SQL Server/Rails interaction, probably related to the fact that Ruby and SQL use different quoting systems. Just not sure how to navigate it.

Comment: Have you tried using an `odbc` connection?

Comment: I haven't tried odbc. It's not my app, just a legacy one I inherited to fix. I'll give odbc a try if nothing turns up to get it working with the sqlserver adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Further investigation took me to the github page for the [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter)

There, I found issues [230](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/230) and [226](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/226), with similar problems to mine. Apparently using '.' in database, table or column names will present similar problems. As these were created in 2012 and are still open, it doesn't look like a fix is coming anytime soon. In the comments there are a few ideas to monkey-patch it into working. Guess that's the approach I'll have to take to get this working.

UPDATE: For anyone stuck with a similar problem, and the database name is the only issue (not tables or columns), the solution we went with was an end-run around the sqlserver-adapter. We created a SQL user for each database, and assigned a default database to that user. Then, we connected with the user login but left the database name null. SQL Server will connect to the default database in that case.